# Transform array of object into array of object with merged value

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object, something like this:

```
 array = [
{prop1: 'teste1', prop2: 'value1', prop3: 'anotherValue1' },
{prop1: 'teste2', prop2: 'value2', prop3: 'anotherValue2' },
{prop1: 'teste3', prop2: 'value3', prop3: 'anotherValue3' }
```

]

I want to transform it in a new array like this:

```
[
   {prop1:['teste1', 'teste2', 'teste3']},
   {prop2:['value1', 'value2', 'value3']},
   {prop3:['anotherValue1', 'anotherValue2', 'anotherValue3']}
]
```

Comment: what goes wrong? btw, why different objects in the result set?

Comment: the result has an array as value with all the values from on property from the first array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `Object.keys` of the first obj `array[0]`. You can use `map` to create new object with the consecutive keys and spread operator with `reduce` method to merge the previous and the current values in your array.

```js
const array = [
  { prop1: 'teste1', prop2: 'value1', prop3: 'anotherValue1' },
  { prop1: 'teste2', prop2: 'value2', prop3: 'anotherValue2' },
  { prop1: 'teste3', prop2: 'value3', prop3: 'anotherValue3' }
];

 const arrayTransformed = Object.keys(array[0]).map(key => ({
    [key]: array.map(obj => obj[key])
 }));

console.log(arrayTransformed)
```

Comment: Do you really need `Object.entries` here if you're not gonna use the values?

Comment: Right , Object.keys will suffice :)

Answer (score 1):

Here, the first loop will iterate over all the keys and the second loop will iterate over all the objects for the particular key.

```js
const array1 = [
    {prop1: 'teste1', prop2: 'value1', prop3: 'anotherValue1' },
    {prop1: 'teste2', prop2: 'value2', prop3: 'anotherValue2' },
    {prop1: 'teste3', prop2: 'value3', prop3: 'anotherValue3' }
]

let array2 = []
Object.keys(array1[0]).forEach(function(data){
    let obj = {};
    obj[data] = []
    array1.forEach(item => obj[data].push(item[data]))

    array2.push(obj)
})

console.log(array2)
```

Comment: The result is not an array. OP wants an array.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const array = [{
  prop1: 'teste1',
  prop2: 'value1',
  prop3: 'anotherValue1'
}, {
  prop1: 'teste2',
  prop2: 'value2',
  prop3: 'anotherValue2'
}, {
  prop1: 'teste3',
  prop2: 'value3',
  prop3: 'anotherValue3'
}];

const result = Object.values(array.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    acc[key] = acc[key] || {
      [key]: []
    };
    acc[key][key].push(value);
  });
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

You can use reduce to achieve the result.

Answer (score 1):

You could take the entries, group by key and  build an object from the entries as result set.

```js
const
    data = [{ prop1: 'teste1', prop2: 'value1', prop3: 'anotherValue1' }, { prop1: 'teste2', prop2: 'value2', prop3: 'anotherValue2' }, { prop1: 'teste3', prop2: 'value3', prop3: 'anotherValue3' }],
    result = Object
        .entries(data.reduce((r, o) => {
            Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => (r[k] ??= []).push(v));
            return r;
        }, {}))
        .map(p => Object.fromEntries([p]));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```